# Interpreting multiple predictor polynomial regression output in R

Tags: r, non-linear-regression, poly

I need to export a final multivariate polynomial regression equation from R to another application.  I do not understand one portion of the regression output. The regression uses the polym() function. The summary table is posted below.

```
ploy_lm <- lm(df$SV ~ polym(df$Indy, df$HI, degree = 3, raw = TRUE)
summary(ploy_lm)
```

The table below says polym input for "df$Indy, df$HI, degree = 3, raw = TRUE".

|  | Estimate |
| --- | --- |
| Intercept | -8.903 |
| (polym input)1.o | 1.189E0 |
| (polym input)2.o | -1.651E-2 |
| (polym input)1.1 | 8.247E-4 |

How do I translate the results into a final regression equation?  Does the value at the end of the first column (e.g. from the last row: "polym(df$Indy, df$WM_HI, degree = 3, raw = TRUE)**1.1**") signify the exponent value?

Comment: That is the interaction between the first order of the first variable and first order of the second variable. Ie x*y..

Comment: What would the final equation be?

Comment: What do you mean by final equation? You have not provided any data. And so far the coefficients provided do not have degree 3, yet you specified degree 3. So this is justnpart of a bigger coefficient matrix

Comment: Can't the equation be derived from the summary results?  Would it be:

y = -8.903 + 1.189*x -1.651E-2 * x^2 + 8.247E-4 * x^3?

Comment: But these are not the full summary results are they?. Can you post the results of using poly rather than polym?

Comment: Poly doesn't work since there are multiple predictors.  These are the full summary results.

Comment: Poly would work. Just do `poly(cbind(your multiple predictors), degree=...,raw=TRUE)`

Comment: Using cbind worked.  How do I interpret the summary table to build an equation?

Comment: You should have `8.903 + 1.189*x -1.651E-2 * x^2 + 8.247E-4 * x1*x2` interaction term

Comment: Note that when you have 1.0 means use x1, when you have 2.0 means use x1^2, when you have 0.1 means use x2 and 0.2 means use x2^2 then when you have 1.1 use x1x2(interaction) also you shoukd avoid using $ within poly. Just use the data parameter within your model function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example with a predefined function:

```
x1<-  runif(20, 1, 20)
x2 <- runif(20, 15, 30)

#define a function for y
y <- (1 - 3*x1 + 1/5*x2 - x1*x2 + 0.013*x1^2 + 0.2 *x2^2)
#add some noise to prevent a warning on the fit
y <- y +rnorm(20, 0, 0.01)

ploy_lm <- lm(y ~ polym(x1, x2, degree = 2, raw = TRUE))
summary(ploy_lm)
  
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ polym(x1, x2, degree = 2, raw = TRUE))

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.017981 -0.007537  0.001757  0.005833  0.018697 

Coefficients:
                                           Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                               9.588e-01  7.158e-02    13.39 2.25e-09 ***
polym(x1, x2, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.0 -3.003e+00  2.820e-03 -1064.88  < 2e-16 ***
polym(x1, x2, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)2.0  1.315e-02  9.659e-05   136.15  < 2e-16 ***
polym(x1, x2, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.1  2.059e-01  6.536e-03    31.51 2.12e-14 ***
polym(x1, x2, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.1 -1.000e+00  1.059e-04 -9446.87  < 2e-16 ***
polym(x1, x2, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.2  1.998e-01  1.511e-04  1322.68  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.01167 on 14 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 6.298e+08 on 5 and 14 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16            

#In summary
# Term         model    Fitted
# Intercept     1        .959
# x1           -3       -3
# x1^2          0.013    .0132
# x2            0.2     .206
# x2^2          0.2     .1998
# x1 * x2      -1       -1
```

The first digit after the ")" is the power of the first term and the number after the "." is the power of the second term.